# Neural Networks / Machine Learning: Handling timestamped data with no clear interval

Tags: machine-learning, timestamp, neural-network, unix-timestamp

I have data where each vector has a few features and then a timestamp (in unix epoch format with milliseconds). I want to feed this into a Recurrent NN (but I imagine this applies to all forms of ML).

How to I either format the data or preprocess it to handle timestamped data?

---

Note: the timestamp is very important ~1s is the most that is tolerable. However there may be multiple values within a 1s interval. I would also need to be able to handle this if I decrease the temporal precision.

---

PS: I'm using Python with [Keras](http://keras.io/) NNs

Comment: Here is a brief answer if that helps
http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14634/how-to-encode-date-as-input-in-neural-network